# How to make apps remember window position?

Tags: files

Most importantly Files. On empty desktop it launches in the middle, which is ok. But if I have for example chromium open, and I open files, it opens in top left corner which is very annoying.

And also, I have to click Files twice to see the folder. First click opens it in behind of chromium, and only second click opens it to screen???

TBH I think this behavior just started today. I dont remember changing anything

EDIT: Ok, i tried to logout to fix it. Logout button didnt do anything. Then I tried restart, it worked and fixed everything, including logout button. Now everything is good, except my login screen wallpaper randomly changed to the default mountain one (never did that before after restarts). Very weird random behaviour!

Comment: OP, I've marked this question as being "unclear what you're asking". Is there still a problem or has it been resolved?

Comment: Right now it's solved, but who knows it might happen in future. That Files (and other programs) opening sometimes in the background I already found from bug tracker (reported 2013!) https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1220179

Somehow, that window position bug was connected to it, as it happened at same time, but never before.

Answer (score 0):

> And also, I have to click Files twice to see the folder. First click opens it in behind of chromium, and only second click opens it to screen???

Thats default behavior for Elementary OS AFAIK